# Стилистические и жанровые особенности интервью

Tags: стилистика

Подскажите, как описать стилистические и жанровые особенности интервью по следующему плану:

1. Сфера употребления текста.
2. Доминирующая функция языка.
3. Цель создания данного конкретного текста.
4. Вид и форма речи.
5. Стиль текста.
6. Стилевая разновидность (подстиль).
7. Лексические особенности текста (указать наиболее типичные для данного стиля и жанра слова и обороты на примерах из собственного текста).

Comment: @Иван931, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Интервью - один из жанров публицистического стиля.

1. Его сфера употребления - телевидение, радио, газеты, журналы.
2. Доминирующая функция языка - воздействовать на сознание и чувства читателя, слушателя; сформировать определённое отношение, привлечь внимание к событиям, фактам, побудить к действиям.
3. Цель создания данного конкретного текста - не вижу текста, смотрите сами.
4. Вид и форма речи - чаще всего диалог - беседа в форме вопросов и ответов. Самый распространенный вид. Журналист, наряду с основными вопросами, задает собеседнику уточняющие, получает информацию о значительном факте. Но бывает и интервью-монолог (выглядит в форме ответа интервьюируемого на вопрос корреспондента, поставленный в начале текста), интервью-портрет (на первый план выходит создание портрета интервьюируемого). В тексте появляются элементы биографии, присутствуют мнения героя по различным темам. Автор, посредством разнообразных вопросов, раскрывает личность человека.
   Интервью-беседа – журналист ведет беседу с человеком на равных. Предмет разговора – проблемная актуальная ситуация, выход из которой следует найти в процессе разговора. Журналист не только получает от собеседника информацию, но и сам высказывает свое мнение. Возможен спор. Обратные вопросы), коллективное интервью (представление о мнении нескольких людей по тем или иным вопросам), анкета (массовый вид интервью, заочная беседа. Вопросы задаются на газетном листе, автор изучает поступившие в редакцию ответы и пишет текст. Иногда в издании существует рубрика «Анкета», в которой герой отвечает на стандартный набор вопросов), блиц-опрос (целью является получение мнений людей различного социального статуса по одному актуальному вопросу).
5. Стиль текста - публицистический.
6. Стилевая разновидность (подстиль) - газетно-публицистический (или журнальный, телепублицистика, радиопублицистика).
7. Лексические особенности текста - нейтральная лексика в сочетании с клише (иметь значение, поставить вопрос, здравый смысл), соединение высокой лексики с разговорной, общественно-политическая лексика, термины, тропы и фигуры речи.